# Can't play Video when video loop property is set to true in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, video, playback

If I have a video without the 'loop' property set, then the video ends and I make 'loop' property true, I can no longer call Play on the video unless loop property is set to false first.

HTML

```
<video id="my_video" autoplay>
    <source src="vid.myvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Jquery

```
$('video#my_video').prop('loop',true);
$('video#my_video').get(0).play();        //fail :(

$('video#my_video').prop('loop',false);
$('video#my_video').get(0).play();       // win :O
```

Any ideas?

Chrome 26.0.1410.64

Jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Just taking a guess, but this might be a feature to prevent JavaScript from abusing the looping of a video. If the HTML doesn't have the loop attribute set, then the HTML author is saying that the video should not loop. Maybe JavaScript isn't allowed to alter the `loop` property at runtime? Maybe try calling `play()` first, then setting the `loop` property to true?

Comment: You can alter the loop property at runtime. I can take the loop 'off' and 'on' while it is playing. It only occurs if I put loop 'on' after it's finished. A workaround would be to just play the video once I hit loop but this doesn't fix the problem just works around it. Appreciate what you're saying but I was more curious if there was a syntax issue or bug.